# .Net + IIS + Active Directory Issue: The directory service is unavailable

Tags: .net, active-directory

We have a sporadic problem on our two internal website. The problem usually doesn’t affect both sites at the same time.  We use active directory to login to our sites and occasionally we have to recycle our app pool to be able to log in. The error we get before recycling the app pool is:

```
login.LoginUser_Authenticate   The directory service is unavailable.  

at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)  
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()  
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()  
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)  
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()  
at System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.FindUserEntry(DirectoryEntry
containerEntry, String filter, SearchScope searchScope, Boolean
retrieveSAMAccountName, String& sAMAccountName)  
at System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.ValidateUserCore(String
username, String password)  
at System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String
username, String password)  
    at Test1.Login.LoginUser_Authenticate(Object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) in
C:\Websites\ContractManagement\Test1\Login.aspx.vb:line 18
```

We have tried recycling every night when the shop is closed and this doesn’t seem to effect this problem.  We usually go between 2 and 3 weeks without seeing any issue.

I personally think the problem has to do with the fact that we have 2 AD servers and that we are ldap to connect to the domain. i.e. (`LDAP://ourdomain.com/OU=GH,DC=ourdomain,DC=com`).

I know that one of the times we had an issue was when one of the AD servers was rebooted and for whatever reason it didn’t resolve to the other server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried binding to the Global Catalog? Are you disposing all objects that need to be disposed?

Comment: Binding to the global Catalog? Are you talking in A.D.?  Do you have any examples?

Comment: Ever get anywhere with this?  Having somewhat of a similar issue - we have webservices that query AD and return some info.  2 instances on the same server (test and live).  Live for some reason will occasionally start throwing this error, and test won't.  If I recycle the app pool on live, all is well.  I can't see anything in the settings between the 2 that would cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue until I found this post:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1589323.aspx?System+DirectoryServices+NOT+available

in web,config include this line

```
<assemblies>
 <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
</assemblies>
```

This resolved the issue for us

Comment: I'm going to try this out, but I don't understand why this would work.

Comment: Did it help you mechanicum?